# Events is SFML. Switch statement VS if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

I have some code like this:

```
while(window.pollEvent(event) {
    //checking events...
}
```

My question is, should I use switch statement:

```
switch(event.type) {
    case sf::Event::Closed:
        window.close();
        break;
    case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
        //...
        break;
}
```

or if-else statement:

```
if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
    window.close();
else if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
    //...
```

Which is faster in SFML and more readable for others?

Comment: With a modern compiler and optimizations turned on, they'll probably result in the same machine code (and thus have the same speed).

Comment: @Cornstalks I'm using `g++`. I think it's one of the modern compilers, which are you talking about.

Comment: But you'll need `g++ -O2 -mcpu=native`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, I'll overtake it.

Comment: Next time, **trust your compiler** and don't even spend time asking that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a matter of *SFML*, the same question could arise with other kind of similar code (e.g. most event loops, finite state automatons, [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) interpreters; read also about [threaded code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code)).

Regarding performance, in principle, a `switch` would *often* be *slightly* faster, but you should benchmark (and some compilers might [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) a sequence of `if` into the equivalent of `switch` or vice versa). In your case, it should not really matter (because most of the time your application would *wait* for an event in `window.pollEvent(event)` ....).

<sup>Assuming no heavy optimization happens, I would imagine that some rare switches might be *slightly* slower, because e.g. of L1 I-cache being full because the hot code would be too large, etc... But that scenario is unusual.</sup>

If you are curious, read this [*A Superoptimizer Analysis of Multiway Branch Code Generation*](https://www.nextmovesoftware.com/technology/SwitchOptimization.pdf) paper (by R.Sayle) about switch optimization.

Regarding readability, the `switch` is a also more readable.

The **readability argument** seems the most relevant to me; **leave micro-optimizations to the compiler**, they are doing quite well. Of course, don't forget to compile with `g++ -Wall -O2 -mcpu=native` and perhaps replace `-O2` by `-O3` (and perhaps even compile *and link* with `g++ -flto -O3 -mcpu=native` if you care a lot about performance)

<sup>(practically speaking, readability is the only thing which should matter to you in that case)</sup>

If you want to understand how and "why" the compiler optimizes, consider adding to your `-O2` flag  `-fverbose-asm -S` (then look into the generated `.s` file) or even compiling with `-fdump-tree-all` (you'll get *hundreds* of compiler dump files, corresponding to various optimizations passes in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) with some optimization switches (e.g. `-O2` or `-O3`).

Comment: Thanks for great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Switch-case. It's both more readable and more optimizable.