# How can I jump to a relative address, using an offset stored in a register?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, low-level

Intel/AMD says that this:

```
mov rax, 0xabc
jmp rax
```

is not equivalent to this:

```
jmp 0xabc
```

Since the first assumes absolute jumps because of the register, and the second assumes relative jumps. My question is, what if I wanted to do a relative jump where the offset is stored in a register such as `rdi`?

I searched other answers in SO, however they weren't so enlightening.

Comment: Relative to what?  When you `jmp label`, the assembler automatically subtracts the address of the instruction following the `jmp` from the value of `label`, and inserts that value in the instruction.  In ordinary use, you wouldn't ever have a relative offset in a register, because you wouldn't know what offset to use.  The concept doesn't apply.

Comment: Hey @TimRoberts. Actually, it's not ordinary use. I'm simply curious because, since we can do relative short jumps with immediate values, I tried doing them by hand, without using labels. Now I just wanna know how I would do the same but when the register contains the value.

Comment: There's no POINT to it.  We use relative jumps for two reasons: to keep the instruction size down, and to avoid having to patch those instructions when the code is moved.  The same limitations don't apply to register jumps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to add the base address to the offset to form an absolute address in the register and then jump to that.

For example

```
    ; jump table contains offsets relative to jump_base
    ; index into jump table is in rax
    lea rcx, [rel jump_table]
    mov ecx, [rcx+rax*4]
    lea rax, [rel jump_base]
    add rax, rcx
    jmp rax
jump_base:
```

Comment: This is more or less what `gcc -fPIE` / `-fPIC` does for `switch` statements when it decides to make a jump table.  [GCC Jump Table initialization code generating movsxd and add?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52190313) - instead of two LEAs, it makes the displacements relative to the `jump_table` address.  In the "small PIC" code model, all static code+data is within 2GiB of each other.  (It uses a `movsxd` sign-extending load so the displacements can be negative.)